# Validity of a patent in another country

Tags: foreign

If I patented something, lets say an electronic device, could this device be produced in another country freely?

Comment: I mean if I patented in the United States

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A US patent is only valid in places where US law is applicable.

You could freely make a device in another country where there was no patent on the device (assuming there is no other legal barrier), but would not be able to sell it in, or import it to, the US.

Comment: But would it be possible for a US citizen to buy said thing in another country and get it shipped to the US?

Comment: No. Shipping it to the US would be importing it to the US, so that would not be legal.

Comment: @DamianBast Possible? Likely so. Legal? No.